# NHibernate Linq property-ref behavior

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

NHibernate Linq is producing an unexcepted query. Here are my class mappings:

```
public class OrderClassMap : ClassMap<Order> {
    public OrderClassMap() {
        Id(x => x.PersistenceId).Column("RowId").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Version(x => x.PersistenceVersion).Column("RowVersion");
        Map(x => x.OrderId).Generated.Insert().Not.Update();
        Map(x => x.OrderDate);
        References(x => x.Overseer).Column("OverseerId").PropertyRef(x => x.OverseerId);
        References(x => x.Overseer2).Column("OverseerId2").PropertyRef(x => x.OverseerId2);
    }
}

public class OverseerClassMap : ClassMap<Overseer> {
    public OverseerClassMap() {
        Id(x => x.PersistenceId).Column("RowId").Generated.Assigned();
        Version(x => x.PersistenceVersion).Column("RowVersion");
        Map(x => x.OverseerId).Generated.Insert().Not.Update();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Email);
    }
}
```

Here is the Linq query I have:

```
var orders = session.Query<Order>()
                    .Where(o => ((o.Overseer.OverseerId == 1) || (o.Overseer.OverseerId == 2)))
                    .Fetch(o => o.Overseer)
                    .Fetch(o => o.Overseer2);
```

The SQL query that is generated is not what I would expect. Instead of doing a left outer join, it does a cartesian join. Here is a shortened example of the query NHibernate produces:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Overseers v1 ON o.OverseerId = v1.OverseerId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Overseers v2 ON o.OverseerId2 = v1.OverseerId,
     Overseers v3,
     Overseers v4
WHERE o.OverseerId = v3.OverseerId AND
      o.OverseerId2 = v4.OverseerId AND
      (v3.OverseerId = 1 OR v4.OverseerId = 1)
```

The query I expected would be like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Overseers v1 ON o.OverseerId = v1.OverseerId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Overseers v2 ON o.OverseerId2 = v1.OverseerId
WHERE (v1.OverseerId = 1 OR v2.OverseerId = 1)
```

I think it is doing this because I have a legacy database and am using PropertyRef in my mapping. Is there any way to fix this unexpected behavior? Why does NHibernate behave this way? It doesn't make sense to me because by specifying PropertyRef, I'm saying "Use this key instead of the primary key".

Comment: What happens if you remove both of the .Fetch() methods ?

Comment: Same thing, only a separate select is issued for each Overseer when I access their properties (lazy loading).

Comment: Did you see the hbm mappings FNH generates? are they built correctly?

Comment: They are built correctly. When I use the QueryOver api instead of linq, it works as expected, but the QueryOver api has issues with sorting by nested properties (ie: can't sort by "Overseer.Name").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using QueryOver<>, and specify the left outer join.

Comment: I query through an IRepository interface that is not NHibernate specific, so I only have a definition on IRepository for Query<>, but I can look into changing it. Is there any other way to do this with Query<>?

Comment: The QueryOver api is really frustrating me. It doesn't seem to handle nested properties very well and the syntax seems quite lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not enirely sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here but it seems to me you got the PropertyRef mappings wrong.

If you want the `OverseerId` and `OverseerId2` in `Order` to the `OvreseerId` column in the `Overseers` table, then your property-ref shold be `OverseerId` in both cases:

```
References(x => x.Overseer).Column("OverseerId").PropertyRef(x => x.OverseerId);
References(x => x.Overseer2).Column("OverseerId2").PropertyRef(x => x.OverseerId);
```

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. It is OverseerId in both

Comment: @Wili, it should be PersistenceId not OverseerId, see my update to the answer.

Comment: I'm not using the PersistenceId field to do the join. The join is done by surrogate keys. OverseerId is an int.

Comment: @Vadim if the reference was mapped to PersistenceId there would be no need to supply a PropertyRef in the first place.